# DOM tree stays in memory if you remove it with click handler on element inside tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Please consider following sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Detached HTML</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".summary").on("click", ".close", function() {
                $(".summary").remove();
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="body">
    <div class="summary">
        <button class="close">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now please click Close button and then take Heap snapshot (I did in the Chrome browser). Filter results on "Detached". You can see that removed elements became Detached DOM Tree and they stay because of sizzle cache/property.

Is that expected, how can this be handled?

Comment: Do you mean on the web inspector? it keeps this in the element tree?

Comment: Developer Tools -> Profiles -> Take Heap Snapshot. It stays in memory, not in the element tree. I would expect and want it to be garbage collected.

Comment: have a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042492/jquery-remove-and-memory-leaks

Comment: Thank you. In above case elements are not garbage collected hence this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sizzle keep an internal caches, that's why you still see detached elements after remove function.

Don't worry, this is not a memory leak and Sizzle will remove detached element from its cache when the cache is full.

Note that you can set cache size by setting a value to '$.expr.cacheLength' before any dom selections if you want to reduce the size of the cache :

```
$.expr.cacheLength = 1;
```

I read the source code of sizzle and you cannot clear the cache (it is an internal data and you cannot access it) and you cannot set the cache size to zero because when you read the function that create the cache :

```
function createCache() {
    var keys = [];

    function cache( key, value ) {
        // Use (key + " ") to avoid collision with native prototype properties (see Issue #157)
        if ( keys.push( key += " " ) > Expr.cacheLength ) {
            // Only keep the most recent entries
            delete cache[ keys.shift() ];
        }
        return (cache[ key ] = value);
    }
    return cache;
}
```

The last line of 'cache' function :

```
return (cache[ key ] = value);
```

means that there are always at least one element in the cache (the function does not check if the size of cache has been set to zero and always cache the value).

You can see this question too: [jQuery/Sizzle checkContext memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279143/jquery-sizzle-checkcontext-memory-leak)

Comment: Thank you. I've saw this code part as well and also noted that cacheLength would fix it. Was not sure that's the right way to do things though.